# Add Days To DateTime Series

Tags: python, pandas

If a date in a datetime series falls on a weekend (US), I'd like to move that date forward to the following Monday. So far I've come up with this, but it obviously won't work for likely several reasons, least of which because the days parameter of timedelta can't be a series.

```
df['Open Date'] = np.where(df['Open Date'].dt.weekday > 4, df['Open Date'] + timedelta(days=7-df['Open Date'].dt.weekday), df['Open Date'])
```

How can I change this to work with a series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.offsets.BusinessDay(0)` will shift weekends to the following Monday, leaving weekdays unchanged.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-12-20', '2020-12-29', freq='D')})

df['date_shift'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.BusinessDay(0)
```

---

```
         date date_shift
0  2020-12-20 2020-12-21  # Sunday -> Monday
1  2020-12-21 2020-12-21  # Monday -> Monday
2  2020-12-22 2020-12-22
3  2020-12-23 2020-12-23
4  2020-12-24 2020-12-24
5  2020-12-25 2020-12-25  # Christmas Holiday Friday Unchanged
6  2020-12-26 2020-12-28  # Saturday -> Monday
7  2020-12-27 2020-12-28  # Sunday -> Monday
8  2020-12-28 2020-12-28
9  2020-12-29 2020-12-29
```

Comment: I had no idea about this function. This is succinct and awesome. Thanks!